# Como verificar se uma imagem foi clicado ou nao

Tags: javascript, html5

Fiz um exercício usando javascript puro, o exercício pedia para vc clicar em uma imagem de uma lampada "apagada" e, logo em seguida que fosse clicado nessa imagem, o atributo `"src"` dela mudasse e recebesse uma outra imagem, que seria a mesma imagem da lampada "acesa". Eu consegui realizar, porém ele funciona apenas uma vez, depois que eu clico ele não se altera novamente.

A minha dúvida é, como eu posso verificar quando um elemento (no caso uma imagem) foi clicada usando apenas javascript puro ? A minha ideia seria pegar quantas vezes a imagem foi clicada e ir alterando o "`src`" dela em um `loop`.

aqui está o ex que eu fiz mas que funciona apenas uma vez:

Codigo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>

      <div>
         <img src="lampada_Apagada.jpg" id="imagem" 
             onclick="acendeLampada()">
         <img src="lampada_Acesa.jpg" id="imagem2" onclick="apagaLampada()">
      </div>

     <script src="lampada.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
     function acendeLampada() {
     let lampada = document.getElementById('imagem').src = 
 'lampada_Acesa.jpg'
   }

 function apagaLampada() {
     let lampada = document.getElementById('imagem2').src = 
 'lampada_Apagada.jpg'
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No javascript, cria uma variável onde você vai armazenar o estado atual da lâmpada. Dessa forma você consegue controlar depois melhor se a lâmpada está acesa ou não. Por exemplo:

```
let lampada = false;

function acendeLampada() {

    if (lampada) {

        document.getElementById('imagem').src = 'lampada_Apagada.jpg'

        lampada = false;
    }
    else {

        document.getElementById('imagem').src = 'lampada_Acesa.jpg'

        lampada = true;
    }
}
```

No HTML, você apaga uma das tag IMG, mantém essa aqui:

```
<img src="lampada_Apagada.jpg" id="imagem" onclick="acendeLampada()">
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Só uma das muitas maneiras que pode ser feito, basicamente muda a imagem conforme a condição do contador:

```js
let count = 0;

document.getElementById('imagem').addEventListener('click', function() {
  count++;
  
  if(count %2 != 0) this.src = 'https://www.placecage.com/200/300';
  else this.src = 'https://www.placecage.com/g/200/300';
})
```

```html
<img src="https://www.placecage.com/g/200/300" id="imagem">
```

Comment: vamo la, eu nao entendi a parte do [0] e nem a parte do this.src , pq elas sao necessárias ? Obrigado desde já !

Comment: Certo Giovanni, o **[0]** quando faço isto `document.getElementsByTagName` eu estou dizendo para pegar a tag **img**, só que isso me retorna uma **`Nodelist`** ou seja um array de tags img, mesmo que no Html tenha apenas 1, aí preciso do [0] pra *"dizer"* que quero a primeira tag da Nodelist, **lembrando que na maioria da linguagens de programção** um índice de um array começa no **`0`**.

Comment: E se n for muito incomodo, como eu poderia fazer esse msm código com o getElementById ? Obrigado !

Comment: Já o **this** refere-se ao elemento em si, ou seja, neste caso como estou fazendo isto **`document.getElementsByTagName('img')`** o `this .src` é o mesmo que document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src

Comment: Vou editar a resposta com um id.

Comment: Muita Obrigado pela ajuda, já clareou d+ a minha cabeça !!!

Comment: Legal man, para ir vendo mais profundamente as dúvidas que teve pode ler aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName   e aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName